# fastest way to get all links and images from a webpage?

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping

So this isn't relly a problem but more like automate thingy...
I built a website and had to copy loads of content from previous webpage. I did that by copy-pasting the content from old page to the new page made with wordpress.

All link and images in the content still point to the old page. So I'd like to find something like a webscraping tools which would analyze list of selected links and then output would be all link pointing outside of my webpage and list of all images that I have to download

Comment: you can simply made all your link absolute so it will not depend on the page you are on !

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your old and new websites are going to have the same URL structure, here is a bookmarklet that you can save as a bookmark to your toolbar.

To make your job easy, open an old website page, and simply click on the bookmarklet button you've saved (code below). This code will replace the links from old website to new website. The images will be treated similarly. Next, you can copy the updated content and paste it into the editor of your new website (wordpress admin).

On the developer's console (F12 key), you will get a list of all the images that you have to download.

```
javascript:(function(){
    var jqscript = document.createElement('script');
    jqscript.onload = function() {
        // treat the <a> tags
        jQuery('#my-content-container').find('a[href^="http://my-old-website.com"]').each(function(i, anchor) {
            jQuery(anchor).attr('href', jQuery(anchor).attr('href').replace('http://my-old-website.com', 'http://my-new-website.com/new-directory'));
        });
        // treat the <img> tags, and make a list of images to download
        var images_to_download = [];
        jQuery('#my-content-container').find('img').each(function(i, image) {
            images_to_download.push(jQuery(image).attr('src'));
            jQuery(image).attr('src', jQuery(image).attr('src').replace('http://my-old-website.com', 'http://my-new-website.com/new-directory'));
        });
        // output a list of images to the developer console
        console.log(images_to_download);
    };
    jqscript.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js";
}());
```

P.S. To save this bookmarklet code, rightclick the toolbar of your browser and create a new bookmark, and enter the above code as the Location/URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an option you should think about: You could use absolute path instead of Relative path, this will help you reuse code without to have to remap every link in it.

Relatif Path :

```
<a href="/pictures/tahiti-vacation/tahiti.html">Read about my Tahiti vacation.</a>
```

Absolute path :

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/pictures/tahiti.html">Read about my Tahiti vacation.</a>
```